# How to refer to arbitrarily names columns in R using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to do some regression matching using the following code:

```
library(data.table)
colCount = 3
Test = data.table(ID=c(1,2,3),R1=c(1,1,1),R2=c(1,2,3),R3=c(4,2,1))
Compare = data.table(ID=c(1,2,3),R1=c(2,1,2),R2=c(6,2,3),R3=c(1,1,4))
# Example, in real run, I know colCount will give the arbitrary number of data columns in Test and Compare; I will not know their names

for (i in 1:nrow(Compare)){
  Test[,paste0('Factor_',i):=sum(Compare[i,2:(1+colCount)]*.SD)/sum(.SD*.SD),.SDcols=2:(1+colCount),by=1:nrow(Test)]

  Test[,paste0('Error_',i) :=sum((Compare[i,2:(1+colCount)]-.SD*paste0('Factor_',i))^2),.SDcols=2:(1+colCount),by=1:nrow(Test)]
}
```

The paste on the second to last line does not work as I was hoping; is there a better way to refer to columns with generated names?

Also more generally, is there a smarter way to do this? The sum-by-row method I'm doing seems way too complicated, but I couldn't get it working using matrix math or lapply instead

Comment: use `get(paste(...))`

Comment: Can you share an example of the desired output?